# using web fonts?

Tags: fonts

I did read somewhere that using web fonts is not a good idea as it makes the web pages to load slow or can cause any other problems, is it true? Is the use of web font not recommended generally? Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Not a programming question.  Perhaps this question is better suited to http://doctype.com/  or you might find something here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=fonts

Answer (score 0):

I'm using web fonts in my website, and I would say that as long as you have a backup font specified so that the reader can see something while the font is loading or in case it fails, there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should help: http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/comparison-of-web-fonts-solutions-7d0b3w9

Answer (score 0):

It may also depend on how you reference the web font. If it is a request to another hosted site it can take longer. You could also try hosting the web-font on your site itself, but that may pose some problems as well. I agree with Gaurav, have a good standard backup as well.